# Including Bootstrap to Crossrider project

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, crossrider

I'm working on Crossrider project, which should be styled as bootstrap(both js and css).
I tried to include them as other js files inside extension.js, but instead of styling popover, current site was styled.
At the moment I'm using standard `<link>` and `<script>` tags inside popover.html.

What is the best way to attach those files to project?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot to go on here, but from the description provided it seems you are injecting the bootstrap components into the page scope and hence experiencing conflicts with sites using bootstrap. I suggest you make your bootstrap classes unique to avoid this issue. I found the following site which might help you get started: https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap

[**Disclosure:** I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Good idea, but where should I include those files? The same way I'm doing it now(by script and link tags inside popover.html) or in extension like all popup js classes?

Comment: Since it works at the moment and the only issue is the conflict, I would recommend continuing the existing method with the conflict resolution changes suggested.